# CI server, lunt build or Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, luntbuild

My company currently uses lunt build as CI server. Hudson now forked to Jenkins, seems pretty powerful to me. I quickly installed it on tomcat, and the GUI seems to be quite powerful for setting up jobs, plus there is over 400 developer plugins and counting!

I was going to ask is it possible to do a POC with Jenkins.

Do any of you guys have experience with both or know the pros and cons i can use when i submit my proposal?

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our small company's software team switched from Luntbuild to Jenkins (née Hudson) back in January, 2010, after using Luntbuild for three years.  Every developer, including one manager, agrees that Jenkins is cleaner, simpler, and easier to use.

I found jobs (builds) much easier to set up and configure, in Jenkins, especially for projects built from different repository URLs.  Documentation is neither project's strong-suit, but Luntbuild's seems more voluminous while being less useful.  Jenkins' community is vibrant.

Beyond my personal experience, you may wish to consider the Wikipedia article titled [Comparison of Continuous Integration Software](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to poke around on the actual Jenkins CI site.  Here's a few links that might help your case.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins

There's a spot to "test drive" Jenkins on that page.  It sounds like you already set up a Jenkins instance, you could possibly add a couple "dummy" builds to that as well.

Also, everything else you might have questions about could be found in the Jenkins wiki:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Home

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @mrust, i have been running jenkins on tomcat and performing dummy builds using svn and maven, plus i have added in some developer plugins. i just wanted to know peoples past/current experience with Jenkins is it worth moving too.